# Identify Equation

Tags: functions

I have a mathematical equation. Can anyone tell the function related to the equation?

> $$ \frac{1}{1+\exp\frac{x-u}{s}}$$

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That's an expression, not an equation (equations assert equality of things); I'm really not sure what you're asking.

Comment: [Fermi-Dirac distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics#Fermi.E2.80.93Dirac_distribution)?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an equation, however the expression looks like the [Fermi-Dirac-Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics#Fermi.E2.80.93Dirac_distribution) used in physics:

$$
f(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp\left(\frac{\epsilon-\mu}{k_BT}\right)} 
$$